# File isDirectory() give false when the file IS DIR

Tags: java, android, file

In my fragment i have list of files and folders, there is and a onclick listener for file position. I`m trying to open only directory and not files but my method isDirectory() always give me false even if the file is directory.

my code

```
void fileList(String s) {
    currentPath = s;
    items = new ArrayList<String>();
    path = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(s);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        File file = files[i];

            if(!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()) {
            path.add(file.getPath());

            if(file.isDirectory()) {
                items.add(file.getName() + "/");
            }

            else {
                items.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
    }
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, items);
    ListView myList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    myList.setAdapter(adapter);
    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            File f = new File(items.get(arg2));
            if(f.isDirectory()) { // <-its always give me false here;
                fileList(path.get(arg2));
            }
            else {
                return;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What value are you passing into `fileList()`?

Comment: It is working fine with my test case. You must be specifying wrong location

Comment: In fileList() i past some path, it work fine, i can see the files and the directoryes.

Comment: it is working (while running) because your current directory is always the same directory of the files you are checking. It doens't work when you have to refer those files later...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
File f = new File(items.get(arg2));
if(f.isDirectory()) { // <-always false because it is a new File...
```

Create the file with the full path, not only the name, or it is creating a new empty file in your position with the directory name, instead of pointing the directory...

```
File f = new File(path.get(arg2) + "/" + items.get(arg2));
if(f.isDirectory()) { // <-now it will perform the check;
```

Check if you will need the extra Slash or not, it is untested.

Comment: How to do that, i create the file whit position arg2.

Comment: Yes it work whit "File f = new File(path.get(arg2));" if i set items.get(arg2) or booth it don't work, the file need to be created only from path to check if is dir or not. TY anyway i will check your post as answer :)

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure you are not checking the containing folder (the parent) instead of the current... maybe print something

Comment: One should always provide full path to create file, as @Andrea suggested, It was very helpful to me.